# Can't run Angular 6 built with Webpack 4 and SplitChunksPlugin

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to migrate my Angular 6 application to use Webpack 4 instead of Webpack 3, but I'm getting the following error when I run the application:

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for IntroComponent: (?).
```

The error above don't happen when I use the following optimization:

```
optimization = {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all'
  }
}
```

This generates the following bundles:

- main.js
- main.js.map
- polyfills.js
- polyfills.js.map
- vendor.js
- vendor.js.map
- vendors~main.js
- vendors~main.js.map
- vendors~polyfills.js
- vendors~polyfills.js.map
- vendors~vendor.js
- vendors~vendor.js.map

According to these entries:

```
entry: {
  polyfills: helpers.root('/client/src/polyfills.ts'),
  vendor: helpers.root('/client/src/vendor.ts'),
  main: helpers.root('/client/src/main.ts'),
},
```

Now I'm trying to generate only three bundles and make the application to work:

- main.js
- vendor.js
- polyfills.js

So I changed the optimization this way:

```
optimization = {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    cacheGroups: {
      polyfills: {
        name: 'polyfills',
        test: /polyfills|core-js|zone/,
        chunks: 'all',
        priority: 2,
        enforce: true
      },
      vendor: {
        name: 'vendor',
        test: /node_modules/,
        chunks: 'all',
        priority: 1,
        enforce: true
      }
    }
  },
};
```

This successfully generates the three bundles I want, but when I run the application I get the error mentioned before:

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for IntroComponent: (?).
```

I compared the bundles vendor.js and the previously vendors~main.js and the only difference is this:

```
> /***/ "./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js":
> /*!***********************************!*\
>   !*** (webpack)/buildin/global.js ***!
>   \***********************************/
> /*! no static exports found */
> /*! ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module */
> /***/ (function(module, exports) {
> 
> var g;
> 
> // This works in non-strict mode
> g = (function() {
>   return this;
> })();
> 
> try {
>   // This works if eval is allowed (see CSP)
>   g = g || Function("return this")() || (1, eval)("this");
> } catch (e) {
>   // This works if the window reference is available
>   if (typeof window === "object") g = window;
> }
> 
> // g can still be undefined, but nothing to do about it...
> // We return undefined, instead of nothing here, so it's
> // easier to handle this case. if(!global) { ...}
> 
> module.exports = g;
> 
> 
> /***/ }),
>
```

The others bundles are smaller and looks similar. How can I solve this problem? I'm getting a lot of headaches with this migration.

UPDATE:

I couldn't solve by separating into vendor and polyfills, but I ended with this optimization config:

```
const optimization = {
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    vendor: {
      name: 'vendor',
      test: /\/node_modules\//,
      chunks: 'all',
      priority: 0,
      enforce: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Hi Sandro, did you manage to solve this? I'm also trying to migrate wo webpack 4 and its costing me a lot of precious time...

Comment: Yes, I solved it. I will post it tomorrow, OK?

Comment: @user5328504, I updated the post, but I couldn't solve the way I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update. Out of curiosity, are you using AoT?

Comment: @VinegarStrokes, no, I'm not using AoT.